# Reportviewer not displaying datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have a reportviewer. I want to generate a datatable dynamically and set it as datasource for my reportviewer. The reportviewer is not displaying the data. My code is as follows:

```
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "report1.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource rdS = new ReportDataSource("report", dt);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdS);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Too many things could be going on here. Are there parameters in the report. Is the datatabe compatible with the dataset used to design the report?

Comment: There are no parameters. It is a simple report, where I want to set the datasource as the datatable. Also, I am not using any dataset. I am simply taking the datatable and displaying it

Comment: Well, you can't just pass in a datasource without defining it as a dataset in the report. Also, make sure the name of the datasource `report` matches the dataset name in the report.

Comment: I tried this: 

    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode =   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "report1.rdlc"; 
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1(); 
    ds.Tables.Add(dt); 
ReportDataSource rdS = new ReportDataSource(ds.Tables [0].TableName, ds.Tables[0]);
   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdS); ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh(); Its still not working. Here, Dataset1 is a dataset that I have added to my website

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004307/how-can-i-load-datatable-as-reportdatasource

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "report1.rdlc";
var datasource = new ReportDataSource("report", dt);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"D:\Projects\NIKHIL\NIKHIL\Report3.rdlc; viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\Projects\NIKHIL\NIKHIL\Report3.rdlc; viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0])); viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

byteViewer = viewer.LocalReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
```

Answer (score -1):

If ReportViewer is not Showing Data (just blank pages):
Make Sure:  Make sure the column names in your DataTable matches the ones you defined in the DataSource (Database).  (Example:  if the Database has a columnName called ‘name_first’, your DataTable also needs to have the columnName as ‘name_first’ ).