# How to fill a ReportViewer from a Datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, reportviewer

In other words, how to set the datasource of a `DataGridView` as the source of `ReportViewer`?

I fill datagridview named as DGVData with the tables from SQL:

```
SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd)
SQLDataset = New DataSet
SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)
Form2.DGVData.DataSource = SQLDataset.Tables(0)
```

Datagridview works good, but when I try to fill `ReportViewer` using the code below it returns an error.

**"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource'."**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MainReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DGVData.DataSource)
    MainReport.LocalReport.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pass your `SQLDataset.Tables(0)` to mainReport and set it as datasource

Comment: You mean like MainReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0))

It says 'Value of type 'System.Data.DataTable' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource'.

Comment: Just see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4005131/3682599)